# Dependency substitution in a separate composite build

Tags: android, gradle, build, composite

The include build dependcy substitution works great for the project it is included in like this

```
include ':app'

includeBuild('../lib_project') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.github.myname:lib_project_name') using project(':lib')
    }
}
```

The dependency module defined in the :app project gets subsctituted correctly.

But it doesn’t work in a separate composite build, i.e. when both projects are included into a higher level composite:

```
includeBuild('../app_project')
includeBuild('../lib_project') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.github.myname:lib_project') using project(':lib')
    }
```

}

The dependency module defined in app_project:app does not get subsctituted in this case.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here?  I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed `include ':app'` to `includeBuild './app_project'`, these two projects became independent of each other. So you should put:

```
includeBuild('../lib_project') {
    dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module('com.github.myname:lib_project_name') using project(':lib')
    }
}
```

into `app_project`'s `settings.gradle` instead.

Comment: This contradicts the idea of `separate` composite build which assumes binding several projects under one higher level one in order to `avoid modifing` the inluded projects settings.

Answer (score 0):

This document explains and provides samples about [Composite Builds Declared Substitutions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_composite_builds_declared_substitutions.html)

In composite builds make sure all the subprojects have ${project.group} defined in the respective build.gradle.kts file of each module.
Or add the group inside **subproject{}** in the root build.gradle.kts file.

If this is done the dependency will work with below format

```
implementation("${project.group}:${project.name}")
```

**dependencySubstitution {}** is only needed for the dependency module *undefined:unpublished* ('undefined' is the default value for project.group, and 'unpublished' is the root project name). that is if the group and name are undefined for a project.